# The page should be visible to everyone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The `Pin list` page should be visible to everyone, but he is only visible to the logged users, identically to `New Pin`. Why is this happening? Is there something wrong in my code?

```
<li><%= link_to 'Home Page' , root_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'about' , home_about_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Pin list' , pins_path %></li>

<% if user_signed_in? %>

<li><%= link_to 'New Pin' , new_pin_path %></li>

<% else %>

<li><%= link_to "sign in" , new_user_session_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "sign up" , new_user_registration_path %></li>
```

edit:

```
 before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, exept: [:index, :show]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: Try with `<% unless current_user.blank? %>` and/or verify if `before_filter :authenticate_user!` is in your `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Post your controller code, and your "user_signed_in?" method.

Comment: "The Pin list page should be visible to everyone, and only visible to the logged users" - what do you mean? That does not make sense.

Comment: I did post edits and pasted the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled "except".  You have "exept".  That should do the trick.

Comment: Ruby fault does not highlight errors like Java, thanks !